# How to play notification sound in service worker?

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging to send notifications to users of a web app.
Here is my current setup for firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');


firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': '123456'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();


messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const title = 'New Order';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    renotify: true,
    tag: "newOrder",
    vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
    requireInteraction: true,

  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(title,
      notificationOptions);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  let url = 'https://dashboard.inhouseorders.io';
  event.notification.close(); // Android needs explicit close.
  event.waitUntil(
      clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then( windowClients => {
          // Check if there is already a window/tab open with the target URL
          for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
              var client = windowClients[i];
              // If so, just focus it.
              if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                  return client.focus();
              }
          }
          // If not, then open the target URL in a new window/tab.
          if (clients.openWindow) {
              return clients.openWindow(url);
          }
      })
  );
});
```

I've seen PWAs like Google Chat where the notification will play a custom sound. I'm assuming that would be done here in the service worker but how can I do that?
I've used Howler in the past to play sounds in the browser but that requires some user interaction before it will play the sound. So how can I play a sound in the service worker?

Comment: do you have a link to the Google chat example? That could be a device setting for notifications. You can only make the device vibrate if it supports vibration. No sound AFAIK

Comment: Here it is. https://chat.google.com/dm/jvDlFgAAAAE On second look I think it's an elctron app so that may be how they can play custom sounds.